# Java ServerSocket required for UDP communication?

Tags: java, udp, serversocket

I had following question on the exam:

*"Let us assume that you want to use UDP for a client. Do you need to create a new socket for managing parallel connections in UDP? Why or why not? What happens if multiple clients connect to that socket?"*

The question also referenced a Java class `TCPServer.java`, which creates ServerSocket and later on in a `while(true)` loop, it accepts connections and creates Sockets for incoming connection requests from users.

To my mind, TCP Server is only used for TCP connections, so it is not possible to use the same server side code for UDP client.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.

[ServerSockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) are used for TCP connections. [DatagramSockets](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) (which are still connectionless) are used for UDP.

And to answer the other part, that is, "What happens if multiple clients connect to that socket?" the answer is:

1. if it's UDP, then it's fine, because it's connectionless
2. if it's TCP, then the ServerSocket should see the connection request, and create a new Socket for two-way communication with that client

To answer the "Why or why not" - UDP is connectionless, and therefore a new Socket isn't used for communication. UDP just receives a DatagramPacket, and either drops it (if the app determines that it's invalid, malformed, etc.), or it replies with a DatagramPacket. In UDP there's no connection, no connection state, and no input/output streams.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked you to explain *why* OR *why not*. So in essence if you didn't believe that the ServerSocket code would work for UDP then you had to say why. From your last sentence I believe you know the answer to the question, now you just have to write it down with confidence.