# ServerSocket for datagram type socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a ftp client-server program which currently uses TCP. I need to now make it work using UDP, so using datagram sockets instead.

They way it was working was to create a `ServerSocket` which would listen for a connection, then give that connection to a `Socket`, and start a separate thread for that socket.

But now using `DatagramSocket`, there's no equivalent DatagramServerSocket, so I've no idea how I can give clients separate sockets anymore. Is there a server socket for datagrams?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket sock;
        ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(4444, 600);

        while(true){
            sock = servSock.accept();
            new ClientHandler(sock).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521741/java-serversocket-required-for-udp-communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to give clients separate sockets. You have the source address in each datagram. That tells you which client the datagram is from. You only need one socket in a UDP server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, UDP is a connectionless protocol. Doing decent file transfer would probably mean implementing a decent chunk of TCP-like functionality.

Comment: There is a standard UDP-based file transfer protocol: **Trivial FTP** - [RFC 1350](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350) and various extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket  = new DatagramSocket(PORT_NUMBER);`
```

Will act as a server socket.

alternatively you could use

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
```